# How to fix "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" error in concurrent.futures threading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, web-scraping

My goal is to scrape some links and using threads to do it faster.

When I try to make threads, it raises `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Here is our script:

```
import requests
import pandas
import json
import concurrent.futures
from from collections import Iterable

# our profiles that we will scrape
profile = ['kaid_329989584305166460858587','kaid_896965538702696832878421','kaid_1016087245179855929335360','kaid_107978685698667673890057','kaid_797178279095652336786972','kaid_1071597544417993409487377','kaid_635504323514339937071278','kaid_415838303653268882671828','kaid_176050803424226087137783']

# lists of the data that we are going to fill up with each profile
total_project_votes=[]

def scraper(kaid):
    data = requests.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/scratchpads?casing=camel&kaid={}&sort=1&page=0&limit=40000&subject=all&lang=en&_=190425-1456-9243a2c09af3_1556290764747'.format(kaid))
    sum_votes=[]
    try:
        data=data.json()
        for item in data['scratchpads']:
            try :
                sum_votes=item['sumVotesIncremented']
            except KeyError:
                pass
        sum_votes=map(int,sum_votes) # change all items of the list in integers
        print(isinstance(sum_votes, Iterable)) #to check if it is an iterable element
        print(isinstance(sum_votes, int)) # to check if it is a int element
        sum_votes=list(sum_votes) # transform into a list
        sum_votes=map(abs,sum_votes) # change all items in absolute value
        sum_votes=list(sum_votes) # transform into a list
        sum_votes=sum(sum_votes) # sum all items in the list
        sum_votes=str(sum_votes) # transform into a string
        total_project_votes=sum_votes
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        total_project_votes='NA'
    return total_project_votes

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    future_kaid = {executor.submit(scraper, kaid): kaid for kaid in profile}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_kaid):
        kaid = future_kaid[future]
        results = future.result()
        # print(results) why printing only one of them and then stops?
        total_project_votes.append(results[0])

# write into a dataframe and print it:
d = {'total_project_votes':total_project_votes}
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
print(dataframe)
```

I expected to get this output:

```
total_project_votes
0                   0
1                2353
2                  41
3                   0
4                   0
5                  12
6                5529
7                  NA
8                   2
```

But instead I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I don't really understand what this error means. What is wrong in my script? How can I solve it?

When I look at Traceback it looks like this is where the issue is coming from:
`sum_votes=map(int,sum_votes)`.

*down below some additional information*

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toz.py", line 91, in <module>
    results = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "my_scrap.py", line 71, in scraper
    sum_votes=map(int,sum_votes) # change all items of the list in integers
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: If you look at the whole error message, you will find exactly in which line it happens.

Comment: You might want to look at the value being assigned to `sum_votes`. It's different in each code sample you provided.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you know what `str(sum(list(map(abs,list(map(int,sum_votes))))))` does? Try splitting that into multiple statements and inspect what happens in which step. Look for the moment when something is supposed to be [_iterable_](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), but is an [_int_](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) instead.

Comment: @zvone edit: I found out that when I run the script sometimes I get an iterable element True. But for some I don't know. Any ideas?

Comment: when you get `int` then check what you have in HTML and see this page in browser. Maybe some pages have different structure and you have to use different code to get information. Or maybe server sends warning that it doesn't like bots and scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error:

I should have put:
`sum_votes.append(item['sumVotesIncremented'])`
Instead of:
`sum_votes=item['sumVotesIncremented']`.

Also, because we only have one item here: `total_project_votes`. Our tuple `results` have only one item. 
And that can cause some problems. Because when we do `results[0]` it doesn't behave like a list. 
It is not going to show the whole `total_project_votes` but the first character of the string. (For example "Hello" become "H"). 
And if `total_project_votes` was an int object instead of a string. It would generate an other error. 
To solve this issue, I need to add another object in the tuple `results` and then when you do `results[0]` it actually behave like a list.